# Android TextView break line

Tags: android

How can make `TextView` with break line behaviour in layout ?. Please see image

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with break line?

Comment: Looks like you need more than one textview in same line

Comment: Looks like a Button (or an EditText, or even a TextView) followed by a TextView.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please add some more information. Furthermore show us, what you have tried so far.

Comment: you can try this https://github.com/deano2390/flowtextview library to achieve this. i have not used it but i think it will help.

Comment: Please explain in more depth what do you want to achieve. What does **break line** mean? Try to explain your sketch.

Comment: Okey, thanks for the answer. I will check it tomorrow! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="1" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/rtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's solution not for my case. Because count of textView and EditText is dynamically.